# Using @RequiredStringValidator messageParams in Struts 2

Tags: validation, annotations, struts2, ognl, messageformat

In my message resources file i have following lines:

```
error.required={0} is required
labels.email=E-mail
```

To validate e-mail field I am using annotation validators, like this:

```
@RequiredStringValidator(key="error.required")
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
```

My question is: how can I pass the `labels.email` resource value to the `{0}` param to the message using `RequiredStringValidator` annotation? I was trying with `messageParam` property but without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@RequiredStringValidator(message = "${getText('error.required', new java.lang.String[] {getText('labels.email')})}")
```

The `getText()` could be used if your action extends `ActionSupport` to get the resource messages by the key specified as a parameter. It applied two times in the same expression to build your message. First time without parameter, second with the parameter and used overloaded `getText()` implementation.

Comment: Thanks! FQCN resolves problem. But you can edit the code and use apostrophes inside `getText` method - then it is valid :).

Answer (score 0):

How about like this?

```
@RequiredStringValidator(key="error.required", params={"1",getText("labels.email")})
```

or in Action-validation.xml

```
<field name="hove">
    <field-validator type="required">
        <message key="error.required">
            <param name="1">getText('labels.email')</param>
        </message>
    </field-validator>
</field>
```

Parameterized message might be rendered.